# How / Where can I add “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff” in all responses which contain user input

Tags: javascript, php, xss, content-type, codeigniter-3

**Issue background**

There was no "X-Content-Type-Options" HTTP header with the value nosniff set in
the response. The lack of this header causes that certain browsers, try to
determine the content type and encoding of the response even when these
properties are defined correctly. This can make the web application vulnerable
against Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks. E.g. the Internet Explorer and
Safari treat responses with the content type text/plain as HTML, if they
contain HTML tags.

**Issue remediation**

Set the following HTTP header at least in all responses which contain user
input:

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

**How and Where do I add this?**

I am using Codeigniter 3.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Add the following header in the index.php file used to set APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT:

```
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
```

Alternately you can set it on the apache server (preferred). You can enable it by modifying your Apache settings or your .htaccess file, and adding the following line to it:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, will try it out. However, my colleague told me to use Output.php core library of Codeigniter. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html . I searched for creating custom functions in output.php but couldn't found one (or) understood one. If you could help me out with that, It would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Well like I said if you set it up on the server you need not do anything. You can enable it by modifying your Apache settings or your .htaccess file, and adding the following line to it: <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Codeigniter 3.0.1
Go To system --> core --> Output.php --> __construct() 

and add 
`$headerTemp = 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff';
 $this->headers[] = array($headerTemp, TRUE);`